# Exceptions being thrown with getting a status with twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I was trying to follow the docs here: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/ShowStatus.java but appear to have gone wrong somewhere. I'm trying to do something slightly different then the docs however. I am not taking args, and am using a hardcoded username instead. Here is the code that is troubling.

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;

public class ChrisTwitter {
    public Status status;
    public ChrisTwitter (){
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        try {
            Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong("rye761"));
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas? Oh and here is what I get in the console: (new stack trace)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    TwitterFactory.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type
    The method Page(int, int) is undefined for the type ChrisTwitter

    at com.github.ryebread761.lockergnome.ChrisTwitter.<init>(ChrisTwitter.java:16)
    at com.github.ryebread761.lockergnome.Base$CTListener.actionPerformed(Base.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6375)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6140)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4737)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:684)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:657)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:655)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:654)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Check the imports of your project. Seems like the compiler can't find some references.

Comment: The following are imported, not sure what else would be needed: `import java.awt.List;

import twitter4j.Paging;
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.*;`

Comment: Now that I notice, the unresolved compilation problem is not about a broken or inexistent import but because the compiler understands that Page is a method of your particular class `ChrisTwitter`. Sorry to bother but, can you please post (or update) the code you're using?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse an alphanumeric string to long and that's throwing the NumberFormatException:

```
Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong("rye761"));
```

Since you're not catching a NumberFormatException in your try-catch block the exception propagates. To prevent this you should validate the input you try to parse before doing so or adding an aditional catch for that NumberFormatException.

**EDIT**

To get the latest tweet of an user, you can take this approach:

First of all define the paging of your request. In this case just ask for one page and one tweet per page (If I'm not mistaken it will be the latest one). Then you issue the request directly, since you're consulting a tweet and you're not doing anything else you don't need to authenticate AFAIK.

```
Twitter latestTweetChecker = new TwitterFactory.getInstance();
Paging page = Page(1,1);
List<Status> statusList = latestTweetChecker.getUserTimeline("rye761",page);
```

There, you'll have the status you need. Just grab the information you need with the [corresponding methods](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html).

Comment: So no way to just get the ID of a single user? All I'm trying to do is get the latest tweet from 1 person, no way to find their ID and do it?

Comment: @ryebread761 I think I'm starting to get the idea. You just want to get the last tweet of an user without setting new statuses or whatever?

Comment: Yep all I need, just the latest tweet from a user!

Comment: @ryebread761 O_o... care to post the stack trace in your question as an edit, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

[Long.parseLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29)("rye761")

Even though input for parseLong is of format String, characters in the String must be all decimal digits, which is not case with `rye761`. So, you are getting exception

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' (\u002D') to
>   indicate a negative value.

Comment: I dont think you can. I think you need to revisit the API for other alternatives.

Comment: @ryebread761 Why would you want to convert it anyway? The showStatus method receives a `long` type parameter that is the status ID, not the username if that's what you're thinking. I can be mistaken tough.

Comment: You were right, thanks, how can I find the ID of a user then? :/